# MGF of the product of a exponential and a bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, moment-generating-function

Let $=$ , where $X$ and $Y$ are independent,  ~(0.01) and ∼(0.3)

Is there a way to find the m.g.f of ?

I know that I can find the C.D.F by doing as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381384/the-distribution-of-the-product-of-a-bernoulli-an-exponential-random-variable).

Initially I tried to find de P.D.F using the C.D.F and determine the M.G.F by hand, but I can't find a way to determine the P.D.F too.

Comment: Since $XY$ is what is called a _mixed_ random variable (it is neither a continuous random variable like the exponential random variable nor a discrete random variable like the Bernoulli random variable), it does not have a P.D.F. in the usual meaning of the term. The C.D.F. is discontinuous at $0$ and so you can't find the C.D.F .and then take the derivative and call the derivative the P.D.F.: the derivative is undefined at $0$. But, Yes, there _is_ a way to find the MGF of $XY$ from first principles.

Comment: Since $Z$ is a *mixture* of an Exponential distribution and an atom at $0,$ its mgf can be obtained as a mixture (with the same weights) of the mgfs of its component distributions.  This follows directly from the definitions.

Comment: Ok, so can I solve using law of total expectation? I didn't understand what do you mean first principles. Sorry if It is a silly question, I'm relatively new to probability.

Comment: $$\mathbb E[\exp\{tXY\}]=\mathbb E_Y[\mathbb E[\exp\{tXY\}|Y]]$$

Comment: You start by finding noting that $XY = X$ with probability $0.3$ and $XY=0$ with probability $0.7$.  Then you find the moment generating function of $X$ and the  moment generating function of $0$.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: I think I managed to solve: $$E[e^{(tXY)}] =E[e^{(tXY)}|Y] =E[e^{(tXY)}|Y=1]P(Y=1) + E[e^{(tXY)}|Y=0]P(Y=0) =E[e^{(tX)}]P(Y=1) + E[e^0]P(Y=0) = 0.3E[e^{(tX)}]  +0.7 = 0.3M_X(t) + 0.7$$. Am I doing it correctly? @kjetilbhalvorsen This is not a homework problem, I'm studying probability and started to think about the MGF of a product of an exponential and a bernoulli r.v, I've used the values just to ilustrate my question.

Comment: Then please answer your own question, in the Answers box!

Comment: "First principles" = definitions and axioms (plus elementary algebra).  No theorems needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using law of total expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tXY}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{tXY}|Y] = \mathbb{E}[e^{tXY}|Y=0]P(Y=0) + \mathbb{E}[e^{tXY}|Y=1]P(Y=1) = \mathbb{E}[e^{0}]0.7 + \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]0.3 = 0.7 + 0.3M_{X}(t)$$

Comment: $\mbox{P}[Y=1]=.3$ not $.7$